# When I manually insert data into database, it duplicates

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

In need of some guidance. I'm manually inserting data into phpMyAdmin and when I click on 'go', then back into the table to browse, it shows the entry twice. Can anyone see why please? Snapshot of the dummy data in the table (duplicated)....

[image: Snapshot of the data in the table (duplicated)]

From there, I go to the 'INSERT' tab along the top and manually enter the data and click the 'GO' to find the entries in there twice.

[image: Example of the insert tab]

Comment: Are you sure you are not pressing the Go button twice

Comment: @RiggsFolly just tried it again and only clicked once and appearing twice again, hmm..

Comment: You are not refreshing the page with an F5 or anything I assume?

Comment: No, I wish I could insert a vid. So just entering the data in the insert tab > then click go > then the next page shows the query in SQL format, then next, then back to the browse the table

Comment: You know when phpmyadmin shows you the query in SQL format, copy that format and insert random values into your tables, does that give duplicates as well?

Comment: @KebabProgrammer no it didn't that time, I think maybe when I click next it's just inserting it again. Beginners rookie mistake!!! Love your display name haha:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click go button and see  1 row inserted message and query and go button. you can click go button again so insert record 2 time.

Comment: Thank you @MehulPatel I hadn't realised that, I assumed once phpMyAdmin gave the query statement, I then had to click on GO. Beginners mistake (won't happen again) Thanking you!!